# Create Ranges from Array of Dates

Tags: ruby, arrays, date, range

**How can I simply the following code** which takes an array of dates and returns an array of ranges for the dates:

```
def get_ranges(dates)
  sets = []
  current_set = []
  dates.each do |date|
    if current_set.empty?
      current_set << date
    else
      if current_set.last == date - 1.day
        current_set << date
      else
        sets << current_set
        current_set = [date]
      end
    end

    sets << current_set if date == dates.last
  end

  sets.collect { |set| set.first..set.last }
end
```

Running the following:

```
dates = [Date.new(2014, 6, 27), Date.new(2014, 6, 28), Date.new(2014, 6, 29), Date.new(2014, 7, 1), Date.new(2014, 7, 3), Date.new(2014, 7, 4), Date.new(2014, 7, 17)] 

puts get_ranges(dates)
```

Produces the following result:

```
=> [Fri, 27 Jun 2014..Sun, 29 Jun 2014, Tue, 01 Jul 2014..Tue, 01 Jul 2014, Thu, 03 Jul 2014..Fri, 04 Jul 2014, Thu, 17 Jul 2014..Thu, 17 Jul 2014]
```

Would appreciate the help.

**Update**

Basically, the result should be an array of consecutive date ranges.

Comment: This question might be better-suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are the elements of `dates` necessarily ordered? Am I correct in assuming that the results you get are what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your result looks a little odd; there are some ranges that start and end with itself. If you are trying to produce an array of ranges in which each range starts with the element at index i and ends with the element at index i + 1, this will do that:

```
 dates.each_cons(2).map { |dates| (dates[0]..dates[1]) }
```

Comment: The OP's result is normal and what is expected.

Comment: What's the goal of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sets = []
current = []
dates.each do |date|
  if current.empty? || date - current.last == 1
    current << date
  else
    sets << current.first..current.last
    current = [date]
  end
end
sets << current.first..current.last
```

this does essentially the same as your code, but is a little cleaner...

Comment: I even think you could use http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition to make that even more consise